# jQuery events- show event doesn't work well in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, click, jquery-events

I have to show a button on click event.

I'm using the following code:

```
$('.message-interaction textarea').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).css('height','90px');
    $('.message-interaction .message-edit .button-blue').show();
})
```

The HTML code:

```
<g:form action="reply" id="${conversationInstance.id}">
                        <div class="convo-body">
                        <textarea class="reply input-text-big" rows="1" name="message" placeholder="Send a reply"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    <div class="mt-16">
                        <button type="submit" class="pull-right button-blue" disabled>Send</button>
                </div>
                    </g:form>
```

For some reason the button is shown only after 2 clicks.

Comment: The HTML doesn't look right. At least, I don't see any elements which use .message-interaction or .message-edit CSS classes.

Comment: The HTML is fine.... I didn't put all the code. I put the relevant element. The form is inside a div with "message-edit" class which inside another div with "message-interaction".

Answer (score 0):

It work for me in Firefox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
         $('textarea').on('click',function(e){
             e.stopPropagation();
             $(this).css('height','90px');
             $('.mt-16 .button-blue').show();
         })
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="convo-body">
         <textarea class="reply input-text-big" rows="1" name="message" placeholder="Send a reply"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-16">
         <button type="submit" style="display: none" class="pull-right button-blue" disabled>Send</button>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```